# Guidance for invoking .jar file through asp.net code

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", " -jar \"C:\\craFVUsubsreg-lite_APY.jar\"");
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = psi;
            p.Start();
```

I want to invoke the utility tool, which is of java.jar file within the "c#" [mvc] application and it is work fine when i run the application through code. However after i published the application and then i try to invoke the same jar file it is not responding or i can say it is not working.
Above is the process code which i'm using to invoke the jar file. Even the user permission i have setted to full control mode.
Kindly guide me, where i am wrong, or is their any way to directly invoke the `java.jar` file without converting to `java.exe.`

Comment: How is it "not responding"? What happens if you attach a Java debugger? What happens if you redirect the Process's standard and error output to a file for inspection?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Java jre / sdk location is added to the path of the server you published to? (@wazdev)